# Программный доступ к проекту Visual Basic не является доверенным

Tags: c#

Не получается запустить макрос vba в проекте c#. Подскажите, что я делаю не так.
Сначала открываю excel файл,а затем прогоняю макрос. Но вылезает ошибка в строке
"oModule = oWb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBA.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);"
Программный доступ к проекту Visual Basic не является доверенным

```
string xlSheetPath = textBox1.Text;
        string ext = xlSheetPath.Substring(xlSheetPath.LastIndexOf("."),
            xlSheetPath.Length - xlSheetPath.LastIndexOf("."));
        int xlVersion = (xlSheetPath.Substring(xlSheetPath.LastIndexOf("."),
            xlSheetPath.Length - xlSheetPath.LastIndexOf(".")) == ".xls") ? 
 8 : 12;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application xlApp = new 
  Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbook workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlSheetPath);
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];


        //Где то тут включить макрос.

        Excel.Workbook oWb;
        Excel.Workbooks oWbs;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
        VBA.VBComponent oModule;

        String sCode;

        //xlApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;
        oWbs = (Excel.Workbooks)xlApp.Workbooks;
        oWb = oWbs.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        oSheet = xlApp.Worksheets.Add();
        oModule = 
 oWb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBA.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
        sCode = "Sub copyTable()\r\n" +
            "Dim colRange As Variant\r\n" +
            "colRange = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) 'Columns where your data 
  is'\r\n" +
            "Dim destColRange As Variant\r\n" +
            "destColRange = Array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17) 'Columns 
  where you want data be copied'\r\n" +
            "n = UBound(colRange) - LBound(colRange)\r\n" +
            "i = 2 'Initial row'\r\n" +
            "newI = i\r\n" +
            "maxLen = 500 'Maximum size allowed in one cell'\r\n" +
            "While Not (Cells(i, colRange(0)) Is Nothing) And (Cells(i, 
  colRange(0)) <> \"\")\r\n" +
            "Text = Cells(i, colRange(n))\r\n" +
            "Do\r\n" +
            "For j = 0 To n - 1\r\n" +
            "Cells(newI, destColRange(j)) = Cells(i, colRange(j))\r\n" +
            "Next j\r\n" +
            "Cells(newI, destColRange(j)) = Mid(Text, 1, maxLen)\r\n" +
            "Text = Mid(Text, maxLen + 1)\r\n" +
            "newI = newI + 1\r\n" +
            "Loop Until Len(Text) <= 0\r\n" +
            "i = i + 1 \r\n" +
            "Wend\r\n" +
            "End Sub\r\n";
        oModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode);
        sCode = null;
        xlApp.Run("[copyTable]", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

....

Answer (score 2):

Дело может быть в самом Excel. Статью по ссылке почитайте. Может поможет. [Запрещен программируемый доступ к проекту на VBA для Office](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-kz/help/282830/programmatic-access-to-office-vba-project-is-denied)
По сути нужно разрешить в выполнение в Excel всех макросов -  изменить настройки безопасности.

Опция включения доступа к объектной модели находится в Excel 2013 по следующему пути Файл>Параметры>Центр управления безопасностью> Кнопка "Параметры центра управления безопасностью..." > Вкладка "Параметры макросов". Вам нужна галочка "Предоставлять доступ к объектной модели проектов VBA"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если у вас другой Excel - попробуйте поискать в сети где она находится. По идее все должно быть примерно там же.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что проблема в этом. Так как создав макрос в самом excel я могу его компилировать.

Comment: Пардон не так выразился. Суть в предоставлении доступа к объектной модели.   Вы все же попробуйте. Я потестил Ваш код в варианте с включенной и выключенной опцией "Предоставлять доступ к объектной модели проектов VBA" - ошибка о которой Вы говорите (Программный доступ к проекту Visual Basic не является доверенным) появляется и исчезает при соответственно отключенной и включенной этой опции.

Comment: А где эта опция в 2010 office находится не подскажите?

Comment: Правда у меня потом Ошибка на строке  xlApp.Run("[copyTable]", ...  Где он ругается что макрос этот найти не может (но это может потому что я код ваш немножко переделал... почему-то 2 книги открываются). Да и вообще это другая история.

Comment: Сейчас добавлю описание более полное.

Comment: Вот я то же думаю, что из-за того, что 2 книга открывается. Но я уже запустился сам. Не подскажите, где мне в коде поправить, что бы все делалось в текущей книге.

Comment: С 1 ошибкой разобрались, но теперь как вы и сказали он не видит это макрос. И наверно вы правы по поводу открытия 2 книги. Но как мне убрать вызов 2 книги?

Comment: У вас строка          Excel.Workbook workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlSheetPath);               дублируется                 
 oWb = oWbs.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);  Но ощущение что дело не в этом

Comment: Мне кажется нужно копать в сторону метода Run. Посмотреть что он запускает, и как... Странно что он не из конкретной книги запускает макрос, а из экземпляра приложения. Предположим в 2 книгах одинаковые имена у 2 макросов запустить. Как Excel тогда узнает какой из макросов  Вообще попробуйте создать еще один вопрос поскольку это уже следующий баг.  =)
 (ближайшее время я не смогу помочь - работать пора - может через несколько часов)

Comment: Все таки я добавил сюда еще один ответ. Но вообще то это не правильно

Answer (score 0):

Еще один баг Вашего кода - с запуском 2 экземпляров Excel мы разобрались. А вот как я переписал ваш пример. Обратите внимание на то как я передал в метод Run имя макроса. Ну и я его еще укоротил маленько

`

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using VBA = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;

namespace MarginMove
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Excel1();
        }

        public void Excel1()
        { 
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = true;
        //Это ваша проблема с 2 книгами
        //  Excel.Workbook workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
        //    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];

        //Где то тут включить макрос.

        Excel.Workbook oWb;
        Excel.Workbooks oWbs;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
        VBA.VBComponent oModule;

        String sCode;

        //xlApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;
        oWbs = (Excel.Workbooks)xlApp.Workbooks;
        oWb = oWbs.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        oSheet = xlApp.Worksheets.Add();
        oModule =  oWb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBA.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
        sCode = "Sub copyTable()\r\n" + "MsgBox(\"123\")\r\n" + "End Sub\r\n";
        oModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode);
        sCode = null;
        xlApp.Run("copyTable()", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }

    }
}
```

`